# Javascript image slider with hide/unhide option

Tags: javascript, text, gallery, overlay

I am trying to find the javascript for an image gallery used on this website:

http://www.number38clifton.com/bedrooms2.php?r=1

Can someone let me know the name of this javascript gallery? I am not very good at javascript. I use basic html and css, but I can follow a tutorial to install a javascript library and have done that before. I have installed lightbox on one of the websites.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Code is on page, and custom solution is in question... and it is not great solution... there are tons of better javascript/jquery slideshows...

Comment: that is a bad solution for a gallery, you should google first for some good ones.. or just use github for open source projects

Comment: Check this one: http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo4 (pure javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ones to choose from, but they usually are called something similar to "lightbox"
An example: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 0):

#### image gallery name: undefined

undefined in the literal sense, it seems that the website has their custom image gallery code, here is it (please beware of license issues)

```
newsArray = new Array()
newsArray[0] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/1.jpg'>";
newsArray[1] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/2.jpg'>";                                       
newsArray[2] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/4.jpg'>";
newsArray[3] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/5.jpg'>";
newsArray[4] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/6.jpg'>";
newsArray[5] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/7.jpg'>";                                       
newsArray[6] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/8.jpg'>";
newsArray[7] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/9.jpg'>";
newsArray[8] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/10.jpg'>";
newsArray[9] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/11.jpg'>";
newsArray[10] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/12.jpg'>";
newsArray[11] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/13.jpg'>";
newsArray[12] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/14.jpg'>";
newsArray[13] = "<img src='images/homeSlide/15.jpg'>";
txt = 1

function fadeNews(step)
    {
        if(step <= 10)
            {
              if ( typeof IE == 'boolean' ) 
                  {
                      document.getElementById('news').style.filter = 'Alpha(Opacity=' + step * 10 + ')';    
                  } 
              else 
                  {      
                      document.getElementById('news').style.opacity = ( step / 10 );
                  }
              step++;
              next = step;
              setTimeout('fadeNews(next)',10)
            }
        else
            {
                setTimeout('fadeNewsOut(10)',6000)
            }
    }

function fadeNewsOut(step)
    {
        if(step >= 0)
            {
              if ( typeof IE == 'boolean' ) 
                  {
                      document.getElementById('news').style.filter = 'Alpha(Opacity=' + step * 10 + ')';    
                  } 
              else 
                  {      
                      document.getElementById('news').style.opacity = ( step / 10 );
                  }
              step--;
              next = step;
              setTimeout('fadeNewsOut(next)',10)
            }
        else
            {
                txt++
                if(txt >= 14)
                    {
                        txt = 0
                    }
                document.getElementById('news').innerHTML = newsArray[txt]
                setTimeout('fadeNews(1)',100)
            }
    }
```